# Nonempty finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have at least one maximal element.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

If $X$ is a finite, nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then there exists some $x_0 \in X$ such that $x \leq x_0$, for all $x \in X$, *i.e.*, $X$ has a maximal element.

Here's my attempt:

We induct on $n$ - the number of elements of $X$. If $X$ is empty, then the proposition is vacuously true. The base case $n = 1$ is trivial. Now suppose inductively that if $|X| = n$ for some natural number $n$, then $X$ has a maximal element. We now show that if $|X| = n + 1$, then $X$ has a maximal element as well. Since $X$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, the well-ordering principle tells us that $X$ has a minimal element - call it $a$. The set $X \setminus \{a\}$ has $n$ elements and therefore - by the inductive hypothesis - it has a maximal element - call it $x_0$. Since $a \leq x$ for all $x \in X$, then in particular $a \leq x_0$. Since $x_0$ is the maximal element of $X \setminus \{a\}$, it follows that $x \leq x_0$ for all $x \in X \setminus \{a\}$. This implies that $x \leq x_0$ for all $x \in X$ (since $X = X \setminus \{a\} \cup \{a\}$), and therefore $x_0$ is a maximal element of $X$. This closes the induction, and the desired result follows.

Could anyone tell me if this is correct/well-written? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your solution is great .

Comment: @RonAbramovich thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.  You used induction *and* the well ordering principle.  Since these are equivalent statements, you can expect there is a way to do this using only one of these.

Only induction: if $X$ has $n+1$ elements, choose an arbitrary element $a$ in $X$.  Then $X \backslash \{a\}$ has $n$ elements, and by induction it has a maximal element $m$.  You can argue that either $m$ or $a$ is a maximal element of $X$.

Only well ordering: Let $Y = \{ -x : x \in X\}$.  By the well ordering principle, $Y$ has a least element $m$.  Then $-m$ must be a maximal element of $X$.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I'll adapt my proof to use only induction, since we haven't properly defined what $-x$ would mean (yet). Thanks!